# Partly apply conditional formatting on a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a matrix table with a measure called `shopcounts` as its values. The `shopcount` measure is composed of two other measures: `total` and `opendate`. The `total` measure applies when the column in the matrix table is "Shop Count", otherwise, `opendate` gets filled in.

`shopcount = IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Shop'[Cols] = "Shop Count", [total], [opendate]))`

Currently, I apply conditional formatting (Background Color - Gradient style) on `shopcount`, and it applies to all the values. I just want to apply the conditional formatting to `opendate` values. How can I do this?